# C# - Generalized SQL Server stored procedure calls

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying something new (for me, at least) and, rather than having specific functions for calling individual stored procedures (1-to-1 ratio of data access functions to stored procedures), I'm trying to write generalized functions that are passed a stored procedure name, as well as string arrays of parameter names and parameter values as arguments.

For example:

```
public DataTable CallQuery(string spName, string[] paramNames, string[] paramValues, string connString)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

    try
    {
        //create a command and assign it to the passed stored procedure name
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn; // new SqlConnection(connString); ;
        cmd.CommandText = spName;

        //add any and all parameters to the command
        for(int i = 0; i < paramNames.Length; i++)
        {
                SqlParameter temp = new SqlParameter(paramNames[i], paramValues[i]);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(temp);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], paramValues[i]);
        }

        //get the data and return it
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, for some reason, when I call this function with parameter values (i.e. paramNames[0] = "@Provider" and paramValues[0] = "AT&T") and make the database call, I catch an exception saying that the stored procedure was expecting the parameter `@Provider`.

I've stepped through and verified that the parameters are being added with their values, but I'm still getting the same exception. Am I missing something simple here?

The reason I'm passing in the string arrays is because there could be anywhere from 0 to 5 parameters per stored procedure (so far...).

Comment: Instead of independent arrays it might be better to pass in a dictionary, hash table or a generic list so it is easy to keep the parameter name and the value together.

Comment: That would probably make sense, wouldn't it? I will get that changed over after I finish testing the rest of the app logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying a type for your parameters. However, the most important thing is make sure you do:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: OMG. I'm a moron. Can't believe I forgot to put that in, and that that is what was causing my problem. Thank you so much!

p.s. I'll mark this as the answer in 6 minutes when I'm able.

Comment: It's an easy thing to miss. That's why we have SO :)